# Passing objects around an event queue in Python

Tags: python

So i have a relatively convoluted setup for something I'm working on explained as follows:

This is is python. and more of a rough outline, but it covers everything I need. Though the process next function is the same so feel free to clean that up if you want.

```
#timer event that runs every .1 second and processes events in a queue
some_event_timer():
    events.process_next()

class Event_queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []

    def push(self, event, parameters):
        self.events.insert(len(self.events), event, parameters)

    def process_next(self):
        event = self.pop(0)
        event[0](event[1])

class Foo:            
    def __init__(self, start_value = 1):
        self.value = start_value

    def update_value(self, multiple):
        self.value *= multiple

    def return_bah(self)
        return self.value + 3

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, number1, number2):
        self.init = number1
        self.add = number2

    def print_alt_value(self, in_value):
        print in_value * (self.init + self.add)
```

That is a barebones of what I have, but it illustrates my problem:
Doing the below

```
events2 = Event_queue2()
foo1 = Foo(4)   ----> foo1.value = 4 here
bar1 = Bar(4, 2)

events2.push(foo1.update_value,1.5)
events2.push(bar1.print_alt_value,foo1.value)
events2.push(bar.print_alt_value,foo1.return_bah())

events2.process_next() ----> should process update_value to change foo.value to 6
events2.process_next() ----> should process print_alt_value in bar class - expected 36
events2.process_next() ----> should process print_alt_value - expected 54
```

I initially expected my output to be 36 6 * (4 + 2)

I know why its not, foo1.value and foo1.return_bah() gets passed as an evaluated parameter (correct term?).
What I really want is to pass the reference to the variable or the reference to the method, rather than having it evaluate when I put it in my event queue.

Can anyone help me.

I tried searching, but I couldn't piece together what I wanted exactly.
TO get what I have now I initially looked at these threads:
[Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

[Use a string to call function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131864/use-a-string-to-call-function-in-python)

But I don't see how to support parameters from that properly or how to support passing another function or reference to a variable from those.

I suppose at least for the method call, I could perhaps pass the parameter as foo1.return.bah and evaluate in the process_next method, but I was hoping for a general way that would accept both standard variables and method calls, as the event_queue will take both.

Thank you for the help

Update edit:

So I following the suggestion below, and got really close, but:

Ok, so I followed your queue suggestion and got really close to what I want, but I don't completely understand the first part about multiple functions.

I want to be able to call a dictionary of objects with this as well.
for example:

```
names = ["test1", "test2"]
    for name in names:
        names_objs[name] = Foo(4)
```

Then when attempting to push via lambda

```
for name in names_list:
    events2.push(lambda: names_objs[name].update_value(2))
```

doesn't work. When teh event actually gets processed it only runs on whatever name_objs[name] references, and if the name variable is no longer valid or has been modified outside the function, it is wrong.
This actually wasn't surprising, but adding a:

```
name_obj_hold = name_objs[name]
```

then pushing that didn't either. it again only operates on whatever name_obj_hold last referenced.

Can someone clarify the multiple funcs thing. I'm afraid I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

basically I need the initial method call evaluated, so something like:
    names_objs[name].some_func(#something in here#)
gets the proper method and associated with the right class object instance, but the #something in here# doesn't get evaluated (whether it is a variable or another function) until it actually gets called from the event queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing in the function to call `func1` and the arguments that should be passed to the function, pass in a function `func2` that calls `func1` with the arguments that should be passed in.

```
d = {"a":1}
def p(val):
  print val

def func1():
  p(d["a"])

def call_it(func):
  func()

call_it(func1)
d["a"] = 111
call_it(func1)
```

Within `func1`, `d["a"]` is not evaluated until `func1` actually executes.

For your purposes, your queue would change to:

```
class EventQueue(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.events = deque()
  def push(self, callable):
    self.events.append(callable)
  def process_next(self):
    self.events.popleft()()
```

`collections.deque` will be faster at popping from the front of the queue than a list.

And to use the `EventQueue`, you can use lambdas for quick anonymous function.

```
events2 = EventQueue()
foo1 = Foo(4)
bar1 = Bar(4, 2)

events2.push(lambda: foo1.update_value(1.5))
events2.push(lambda: bar1.print_alt_value(foo1.value))
events2.push(lambda: bar1.print_alt_value(foo1.return_bah()))

events2.process_next()
events2.process_next() # 36.0
events2.process_next() # 54.0
```

**For Edit:**

In this case you need to "capture" the value in a variable that is more tightly scoped than the loop. You can use a normal function and [`partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to achieve this.

```
for name in names_list:
  def update(name):
    names_objs[name].update_value(2)
  events2.push(partial(update, name))
```

Comment: I clarified some in my original question if you could kindly help clarify, or perhaps let me know if what I want is unreasonable. Thanks.