# Convert string into a function call

Tags: python

I have a string variable with the exact name of a function, e.g.

```
ran_test_opt = "random_aoi"
```

The function looks like this:

```
def random_aoi():
  logging.info("Random AOI Test").
```

The string is received from a config file and therefore can't be changed. Is there a way I can convert the string into an actual function call so that

```
ran_test_opt()
```

would run the `random_aoi` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a string whose content is a function name, how to refer to the corresponding function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719466/i-have-a-string-whose-content-is-a-function-name-how-to-refer-to-the-correspond)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure, you can use `globals`:

```
func_to_run = globals()[ran_test_opt]
func_to_run()
```

Or, if it is in a different module, you can use `getattr`:

```
func_to_run = getattr(other_module, ran_test_opt)
func_to_run()
```

Comment: A more explicit example of this can be found here: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-call-function-from-a-string/

Answer (score 2):

there is another way to call a function from a string representation of it just use
`eval("func()")` and it will execute it

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this, it's worth noting that `eval()` can be [very dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

The tl;dr is you need to understand what the code you're evaluating is doing and make sure it's coming from a trusted source.  Otherwise, this can lead to security exploits and hacks.