# Convert string into a function call withing the same class

Tags: python, string, function, call

How would I go about converting a string into a function call for a function that is within the same class? I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021037/convert-string-into-a-function-call) question to help a bit but I think it has something to do with "self.".

```
ran_test_opt = choice(test_options)
ran_test_func = globals()[ran_test_opt]
ran_test_func()
```

where test_options is a list of the names of the functions available in string format. With the above code I get the error

```
KeyError: 'random_aoi'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `globals()` (the functions are not in the global symbol table), just use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
ran_test_func = getattr(self, ran_test_opt)
```

Answer (score 1):

`globals()` is a function that you should use very, very rarely, it smells of mixing code and data. Calling an instance method by a name found in a string is similar, but slightly less hacky. Use `getattr`:

```
ran_test_func = getattr(self, ran_test_opt)
ran_test_func()
```