# I have error when I use exec() to call functions in python 3

Tags: python, string, exec

I have this simple function:

```
def fu():
    return "great"
```

I need to call it by using a string,

So I tried this:

```
print(exec("fu()"))
```

But the the output I got was:

```
None
```

How do i fix it?

Comment: exec ignores the return value of a function, and always returns `None`, which is why none is printed.

Comment: There are quite a few smilar, maybe this one is closer: [Use a string to call function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4131864/2823755)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in comments says you can not use `exec` for this purpose.
but eval will do what you want, full doc [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do):

```
>> eval('fu()')
"great"
```

> Note that using eval is not the best practice.

There is a better way to access this function with `globals` or `locals` based on where you define your function, and I think it's better to use this instead of `eval`:

```
>> globals()['fu']()
"great"
```